# Read/Write to Android KeyStore from Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to read/write to the Android KeyStore from with Unity? We have one app done in Xamarin which stores the user credentials and we want to use these credentials in a Unity3D app. I found a script to read/write iOS Key chain.

They only documentation I was able to find so far was for creating a keystore in the build settings for an Android build.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Android Keystore System is used to store cryptographic keys.

The feature you want is part of the `AccountManager` API.
You can learn about it from the docs: [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)
and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/identify.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html)